# Facebook pages reviews embedded on own website

Tags: facebook

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get the "Reviews" tab from a company facebook page embedded into the company website - so reviews placed from either the Facebook page OR the website would accumulate together.

Alternatively - I have implemented the simple facebook connect comments on the company site. Is there any way to add a 'Comments' tab to the Facebook page that would show and allow the user to add their comments direct in facebook.